# Post Requests in Python For JSON Objects

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I have a dataframe (df) in pandas which I have converted to JSON formot as:

```
json_obj = df.to_json(orient=records).
```

The json object looks like (say):

```
json_obj = [
    {"a": "xxx", "b":"pqr", "c": 1},
    {"a": "uuy", "b":"abc", "c": 3},
    {"a": "yty", "b":"nnq", "c": 7}
]
```

Now when I send the data using an API URL (urlex (say)) (valid) as

```
import requests

r1 = requests.post('urlex', json = [
    {"a": "xxx", "b":"pqr", "c": 1},
    {"a":"uuy", "b":"abc", "c": 3},
    {"a": "yty", "b":"nnq", "c": 7}
]

print (r1.status_code)

print(r1.content)
```

I get the response code 200 with `**b'{"success":true}'**`

However, when I do the same with

```
r1 = requests.post('urlex', json = json_obj ]

print (r1.status_code)

print(r1.content)
```

I get the response code 200 with `**b'{"success":false}'**`

What am I missing and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `pd.DataFrame.to_json` returns a string:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})
type(data.to_json())
str
```

but the `json` keyword argument of `requests.post` expects a python object. If you want to submit a son string, use the `data=` argument instead:

```
# this submits a jsonified string
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8888', json=data.to_json())
print(response.request.body.decode('utf-8'))
"{\"a\":{\"0\":1,\"1\":2}}"


# this submits the actual json object
response = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8888',
    data=data.to_json().encode('utf-8'),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)
print(response.request.body.decode('utf-8')
{"a":{"0":1,"1":2}}
```

I am not sure whether encoding is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `simplejson` or `json` packages:

```
import simplejson as json

response = requests.post('http://localhost:8888', data=json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records')),
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)
```

Additionally, if you didn't want to orient as records you can use `to_dict` instead of `to_json`

```
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8888', data=df.to_dict(),
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)
```

The reason this works is because the `data` argument in the `requests` package accepts a string.

Comment: @Stan yes, that's an alternative that fixes the problem as well

Comment: Thank you !! I will try your one too.. Always better to have many ways